# Webapi return json with extra double slashes for a path property

Tags: json, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net webapi and returning json response. One of the property in the json response has got a path field. When i check in Console.WriteLine i get the values without additional double slashes. But the json response in postman contains extra double slashes.

Expected:

```
\\test.com\cax\mef\160704\160704Z003.abc
```

But in the json response the output i am getting is:

```
"path": "\\\\test.com\\cax\\mef\\160704\\160704Z004.abc"
```

And my json settings in webapi.config:

```
    var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
    var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
    var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Can anyone help me what is the problem and how to solve this?

Why i am getting extra double slashes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The added slashes are their as Escape characters.

This Could be caused when you asign the URL to the Variable before you return the response via the Webapi. Eg:

```
xObj.path = urlPath;
----------------
xObj.path = urlPath.ToString();
```

It All Depends on where and how you Assigned them.. If they are coming for a Database they could have also Been Stored Like that.

it could also just be the IDE showing it to you Like that. This Often Just Adds the Escape characters to the interpretation of the value.. but when the value is used they are no longer present.

this is how you parse the JSON

```
var jsonResponse = '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe", "path" : "/test/test/adasdasd.com" }';
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
console.log(obj);
```

You Will note that my Example doesn't have the double slashes. That is because if you use the response directly it wont have any either.

Comment: Try using  console.log(obj.path) and see what the value is.

Comment: When i write in console.writeline i get the correct value but the json response is what i need

Comment: @MukilDeepthi Awesome. then Its Assigned Correctly.

I would then not use the Json Response but rather assign the response to a parsed object and use that..

Comment: But i am developing asp.net webapi and returning the response as json

Comment: I Understand. But the Response Surely needs to be used in some way. 

Now instead of Using the Raw Response just Parse the Response to an Object and then use that Object.